# Cycling through documents in a backend archive

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm building a website which will show comics.

I'd like to store each image in a backend file, and then have the site access those files and display them on the front end. I do not want to create a new page for each image. 
Basically like this:

[image: img description]

Similar to what you'd see here:

http://doctorcatmd.com/2011-01-10/doctor-cat

or

http://xkcd.com/1004/

I'd like to know how I can achieve this. Do I need to learn a querying language? Or do I have to actually create a new page for each file I'd like to show...? Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? Also the link supplied has a page for each image.

Comment: This is an announcement. We need a question.

Comment: lol, good point! Okay, I've revised and included a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a separate file containing HTML for every image, doing that is unnecessary and complete overkill. Instead, on the server-side you can generate the page based on a predefined template and insert content wherever you like. You can do this using a server-side scripting language such as PHP.

As far as determining *what* to insert (in your case an image), that's typically done using parameters from the client, usually in the form of as HTTP GET variable. They're (usually) the key-value pairs you see at the end of a URL after the question mark (eg. http://example.com/article.php?**id=3454**).

A *very* basic example of a PHP script that could do what you want is as follows.

```
<html>
<body>

 <?php

  $images = array(
   1 => 'peanuts.jpg',
   2 => 'dilbert.png',
   3 => 'phantom.png'
  );

  echo '<img src="/images/"' . $images[ $_GET['id'] ] . '">';

 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

A URL like http://example.com/comics.php?id=2 would show a page with the dilbert.png image on it.

Comment: This is exactly the feedback I was seeking. I just wasn't sure which language/method to choose to do this. I figured making a new page for each image would be ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, one way you could do this is to use PHP and set up a template page, and then use a query string to determine which comic to show. Something like:

```
<div id="comic">
<?php
    $comic_id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["comic_id"]);
?>
    <img src="<?php print $comic_id?>"/>
</div>
```

In this case your comic ID would be the name of the file and your URLs would look like http://www.example.com?comic_id=comic1.png

This way you have one .php file as the template, but you can have it show whichever image you'd like.

Of course it would require more code to write the pager, which would need to know what the first, previous, current, next, and last comics are. That would require some sort of mapping mechanism for listing and ordering them. You could use a backend MySQL database for that, or something lighter.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I guess php is the way to go.